# displaying images in drop down values

Tags: dart, dropdown, flutter

I try to create a Dart multiple page application.

I have created a page which navigates from the drawer which contains a form. It has a container in it which is used to get user selected item from a dropdown button. 
in this dropdown, i need to give an image in each item. How can I do this with customizing the dropdown button? is it possible ?

i have attached a sample picture of what i needed in my app.

[image]

Comment: You can refer to this link also and 
can customize the class ->https://www.coderzheaven.com/2019/04/16/dropdown-list-in-flutter/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple example to show how to start on that:

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => new _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  var _img = new Image.network("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/89/TUCPamplona10.svg/500px-TUCPamplona10.svg.png");
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("Test Drop"),),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Container (
            height: 50.0,
            child:new DropdownButton(
            items: new List.generate(10, (int index){
          return new DropdownMenuItem(child: new Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0),
            height: 100.0,
              child: new Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                _img,
                new Text("Under 10")
              ],
            ),
          ));
        }) 
        , onChanged: null),),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for the wonderful example and the reply @aziza. here the solution is for displaying a certain image in the drop down view. that's cool, but what i was trying to do is to give different images to each item in the drop down list. is it possible?

Comment: Of course you can, this is only a trivial solution to get you started. The thing you are seeking is to make an object of the list of items you seek (img+text) and then use ListView.builder and feed the list to it and it will iterate over it. Let me know if this is not clear enough I can provide you with an example.